# Simple conditional ES6 Template Literals

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create a simple conditional statement using template literals. I am adding a class name `text-align-left` or `text-align-right`, etc, based on the `align` variable. If `align` variable is empty the class name should not show.

I tried:

```
className={ classnames( 
    someVar,
    ${align} ? text-align-${align} : ''`,
) }

className={ classnames( 
    someVar,
    `text-align-${align}`: align,
) }

className={ classnames( 
    someVar,
    [ `text-align-${align}` ]: align, 
) }
```

The last one doesn't throw any errors but it created multiple classes because `align` has more values. If I choose for example aligb left, save, then choose align right I will get `text-align-left text-align-right` instead of the last chosen one.

Comment: try `align && \`text-align-${align}\``

Comment: That seems to be returning multiple values for each align value, beause the values get saved. Each time its adding a new one sincle `align` wlll be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`classnames` allows you to conditionally include classnames, but you need to wrap the conditional classes in `{}`

```
className={classnames( 
    someVar,
    { `text-align-${align}`: ${align} }
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this:

```
className={classnames( 
    someVar,
    (align ? ('text-align-' + align) : '')
)}
```